# Различие в #include "mylib.h" и #include <mylib>

Tags: c++, include

Почему при объявлении стандартных библиотек компилятор принимает запись `#include <syslib>`, а стоит подключить свою библиотеку, например, вида  `#include <mylib>`, так компилятор выдает ошибку **No such file or directory**?

Однако, при изменении строки `#include <mylib>` на `#include "mylib.h"` все он находит прекрасно.

Великие странности или лыжи просто не едут...

Comment: Чтоб попроще - примерно так... Указание имени файла в скобках приводит к поиску в стандартных местах размещения заголовочных файлов, а в кавычках - к поиску, начиная с текущего каталога проекта). Т.е. такие файлы ищутся *в разных местах*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, [отсюда](http://mycpp.ru/cpp/scpp/cppd_processor_include.htm) (первый же ответ Google на *"Включаемые файлы угловые скобки C"*):

Директива `#include` заставляет компилятор прочитать и скомпилировать указанный исходный файл. Для записи этой директивы используются следующие общие формы.

```
#include "имя_файла"
#include <имя_файла>
```

Имя исходного файла, подлежащего прочтению, должно быть заключено в двойные кавычки или угловые скобки. Например, оператор

```
#include <MyFuncs.h>
```

заставит компилятор прочитать и скомпилировать файл `MyFuncs.h`.

Если имя файла заключено в угловые скобки, то поиск файла будет осуществляться способом, определенным создателем компилятора. Часто это означает, что поиск выполняется в некотором специальном каталоге, выделенном для заголовочных файлов. Если же имя файла заключено в кавычки, поиск файла выполняется другим способом, зависящим от конкретной реализации. Во многих случаях это означает поиск текущего рабочего каталога. Если заданный файл не найден, поиск повторяется с использованием первого способа (как если бы имя файла было заключено в угловые скобки). Чтобы ознакомиться с подробностями, связанными с различной обработкой директивы `#include` в случае использования угловых скобок и двойных кавычек, обратитесь к руководству пользователя, прилагаемому к вашему компилятору. Операторы `#include` могут быть вложенными внутри других включаемых файлов.

Comment: заставляет компилятор прочитать и скомпилировать указанный исходный файл(боль). а я то думал это подстановка препроцессора и флаг для линкера ) Кто писал этот ужас....

Comment: некотором специальном каталоге.... с каких пор /usr/local/include. /usr/include и /usr/lib/gcc "специальные"..... да, и что такое специальные? Может они дефолтные?

Comment: @Andrey Без вопросов - напишите правильный ответ.

Comment: лично у меня нет вопросов, но я удивлен, что Вы поместили эту ересь сюда.

Comment: зачем? есть Ваш комментарий к вопросу, если исправить там "а в кавычках - к поиску, начиная с текущего каталога" на нормальное описание механизма поиска заголовочных файлов в проекте и линковке, то и ответ то не нужен.

Comment: глядя на этот ответ - я оценил Ваш реальный рейтинг (в уме поделил Ваш рейтинг на значение Вашего рейтинга) хД поэтому Вы все-же трепач)))))) А по на тему весомости - это интернет ) тут все имеет вес 0))))